# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error using jsforce in React app (200 OK, CORS Added)

Tags: visualforce, jsforce, cors

I'm having this issue when attempting to access the Salesforce API from my React app (inside a vf page). Seems odd that it would recognize this as a cross-origin request, but I whitelisted the origin, and it still does not work.

Interestingly enough, Salesforce is responding with what appears to be the proper headers and both the preflight AND the GET are responding with a 200 OK (the GET even responds with the queried data), but Chrome still says that access was not allowed.

Here are the headers that Salesforce returns on the OPTIONS request:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-SFDC-Request-Id, authorization
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (my origin)

The init and call to Salesforce:

```js
const con = new jsforce.Connection({
    serverUrl: serverUrl,
    sessionId: sessionId
})

con.query('SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res)
})
```

Anyone else had this issue? It's so strange to me that the data is being returned by Salesforce, I just can't access it.

**UPDATE**

This appears to not be an issue with jsforce, as I attempted to call the API with axios and it produced the same result (200 OK but still no header).

Comment: How are you turning ES6 into JS?  Is there a preprocessor you're not mentioning?  I assume babel is involved in here.  Is that so?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're omitting final semicolons?  And which version of jsforce are you using?  It looks like master is failing its build tests.

Comment: Sorry, using Create React App (which uses babel). v1.8.0 (master), not something I noticed. I'll see if I can find a good alternative and try it.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to use something closer to native to see if the problem lies in jsforce.